# Multivariate Analyses of Matched Case-Control Data

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I'm a medical student and working on some public health research. I'm new to the forum and I am completely stumped right now trying to figure out how to handle the issue of multivariate analysis of case-control matched data. The set up is I have 36 groups, each with 1 positive (case) and anywhere from 0 to 4 negatives (controls). I have been leaving the one group that only consists of a positive out of my univariate analyses.

Of these 36 groups, 24 are high risk (1-24) and 12 are low risk (25-36). I conducted a ~100 question survey with all of these group participants. Some of these questions had binary responses, others had as many as 6 responses.

So far I have been doing Mantel-Haenszel chi-squared tests for univariate analyses of binary equations using the following script:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE) 
data$group <- factor(data$group) 
data$case_control <- factor(data$case_control, levels=0:1, labels=c("Neg.", "Pos.")) 
data$flood_door <- factor(data$flood_door, levels=0:1, labels=c("Flood risk: low", "Flood risk: high")) 

### Array for MH 
mh_data <- by(data, data$group, function(x) table("exposure"=x$flood_door, "outcome"=x$case_control)) 
mh_data <- simplify2array(mh_data) 

### Sample size must by >1 in each stratum. 
## Identify strata with sample size <= 1 
which(apply(mh_data, 3, sum ) <= 1) 

## Remove stratum 23 
mh_data <- mh_data[ , , c(1:22,24:36)] 

### MH test 
mantelhaen.test(mh_data) `
```

This has been efficient for doing univariate analyses of the binary questions, but I have no idea how to do properly do univariate analyses of matched groups for questions that have multiple answers (i.e. what is your favorite color: green, red, yellow, etc). Is there even a way to do this?

My biggest question, however, is how can I possibly do multivariate analyses in R with matched data like this? Is there a multivariate version of Mantel-Haenszel?

Thank you for any and all help.

-A

Comment: This question may be more suited for CrossValidated. StackOverflow is dealing with programming questions. Your's seems to be more about statistical analyses.